# JS DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, dom

I'm experiencing an interesting bug where `elt` is undefined for some calls to `switchToReady`. It seems like the function inside `setTimeout` is passing the same DOM node twice.

```
function switchToReady(elt) {
    elt.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(17, 0)');
    elt.classList.remove('compiling');
}

const compilingElts = document.getElementsByClassName('compiling');
for (let i = 0; i < compilingElts.length; i++) {
    const randTime = Math.round(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(() => {
        switchToReady(compilingElts[i]);
    }, randTime);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* collection, which means that if the class of an element in the collection changes *while you're iterating over it*, or if you add another element with that class to the DOM, then the index you're on (eg, if `i` is `2`) may no longer refer to the old element there - it may refer to the next item in the collection, or the previous item, or it may even be `undefined`. The behavior is pretty unintuitive, so I would suggest using `querySelectorAll` instead, which returns a *static* `NodeList`, which won't change while you're iterating over it.

```
const compilingElts = document.querySelectorAll('.compiling');
```

Other benefits of `querySelectorAll`:

- The selector string it accepts as an argument can be *very* flexible - it's not limited to just classes
- In newer browsers, you can call `forEach` directly on a `NodeList`, thus removing the need for manual iteration and keeping track of indicies:

  ```
  compilingElts.forEach((elm) => {
    const randTime = Math.round(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(() => {
        switchToReady(elm);
    }, randTime);
  });
  ```

Array methods are a lot nicer to work with than `for` loops in many cases. One way to achieve similar functionality on older browsers, using an `HTMLCollection` generated from `getElementsByClassName` is to use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  compilingElts,
  (elm) => {
    // do stuff with elm
  }
);
```

(a shortcut is to use `[].forEach.call` instead, which will accomplish the same thing with less code, but referencing `Array.prototype` is a bit clearer IMO)

Comment: This is awesome - really appreciate the thorough answer. `querySelectorAll` sounds much nicer to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a live list, which, as you have noticed, means that if you remove the class from an element, the list will change (its size).

You could use `document.querySelectorAll('.compiling')` instead, which returns a list that is not live.

Answer (score 1):

Ah dumb mistake. Realized that by removing the class, it is changing the contents and therefore the index of the referenced `compilingElts` object.

Comment: One solution is to start at the end of the list and work backwards